# How to use variables from widgets in other pages?

Tags: widgets, variables

I have a widget where I set some custom url's like register or login. I want to use those variables declared in a widget outside of the widget, in other pages (page templates). How can I save or use, for example, $login or $register variables, in other pages ?

Answer (score 1):

If you save those urls in options table, then using get_option you can use it any where...

Answer (score 0):

If you post relevant codes here (like your widget), it would help us answer more appropriately. Anyway, here's my suggestion based on Rajeev Vyas's answer:

1. Edit your template's `functions.php`; create it if there isn't any.
2. There, you can either, use `add_option` in the global context or [add some hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) like `'after_setup_theme'` to have control over order of its execution.
3. Either way, write something like this in your `functions.php`:

   ```
   add_option('login_url', 'some/url');
   add_option('register_url', 'some/other/url');
   ```

   This will initialize your desired variables.
4. Then, in your widgets and page templates you can use `get_option` function to get retrieve these values:

   ```
   get_option('login_url');
   get_option('register_url');
   ```

You can find documentation to these functions here: [add_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option)

Comment: I'd recommend to use a prefix for those options. If you're not deleting them on uninstall, no one will ever be able to tell if these are core options or left over options.